# Shorter URL Address via .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

My address is

```
http://myadress.com/central/threads/edit?topic=3
```

and I want this

```
http://myadress.com/central/threads/edit/3
```

Can someone help me with this? I tried a lot of solutions, but they dont work for me. The number **3** is only example, It can be **5,6** or any number.

One of the solutions is

```
RewriteRule ^central/threads/edit/([^/]*)$ /central/threads/edit?topic=$1 [L]
```

but its not working.. when i go to

```
http://myadress.com/central/threads/edit/4
```

it redirects me to

```
http://myadress.com/central/threads/edit/4.php
```

> **!SOLVED!** The code is working.. **its must be at the top of the .htaccess**
>
> ```
>  RewriteRule ^central/threads/edit/([^/]*)$ /central/threads/edit?topic=$1 [L]
> ```
>
> Im dumb, i dont tried to place the code at the top of .htaccess...
>   (Sorry for my english..)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: I tried something figure out from that, but its not working.. still.. (sorry for my english)